# My Spring Boot API Controller can manage to show search result sorted in ascending order, but it fails to show the sorting in descending order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As mentioned on the title, my EmployeeApiController fails to sort the search result in descending order when I play with GET method, even though I include Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, sort) in Sort.by().  However, it is no problem showing the search result in ascending order.

Please help.  I am just Spring boot Novice, and please advise if I miss any important concepts

```
package com.jrp.pma.api.controllers;



import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.jrp.pma.dao.EmployeeRepository;
import com.jrp.pma.entities.Employee;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app-api/employees")
public class EmployeeApiController {
    

    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository empRepo;
    

    @GetMapping(params= {"page", "size", "sort"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Iterable<Employee> findPaginatedEmployees(@RequestParam("page") int page, 
                                                    @RequestParam("size") int size,
                                                    @RequestParam("sort") String sort){


        Pageable pageAndSize = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, sort));
        return empRepo.findAll(pageAndSize);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Tou should attach your repository code

Answer (score 0):

This may help you with what you want to do https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html .
Also, add your repository code so you can get a better feedback.